# pydantic-to-typescript giving AttributeError: Config

Tags: python-3.x, typescript, pydantic

I have simple class from which I am trying to generate an interface in typescript using pydantic-to-typescript.

Trying to generate ts interfaces from python using pydantic-to-typescript
I was expecting a ts output file
But I keep getting errors in the CLI

```
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Client:
    clientId: str
    clientName: str
```

when I run in the CLI: `pydantic2ts --module ./model/client.py --output client.ts`

I get below Error:

```
C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\pdf-creator-HARGFuzC\Lib\site-packages\pydantic\_migration.py:283: UserWarning: `pydantic.generics:GenericModel` has been moved to `pydantic.BaseModel`.
  warnings.warn(f'`{import_path}` has been moved to `{new_location}`.')
2023-12-29 03:41:03,954 Finding pydantic models...
2023-12-29 03:41:04,034 Generating JSON schema from pydantic models...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\pdf-creator-HARGFuzC\Scripts\pydantic2ts.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\pdf-creator-HARGFuzC\Lib\site-packages\pydantic2ts\cli\script.py", line 274, in main
    return generate_typescript_defs(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\pdf-creator-HARGFuzC\Lib\site-packages\pydantic2ts\cli\script.py", line 208, in generate_typescript_defs
    schema = generate_json_schema(models)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\pdf-creator-HARGFuzC\Lib\site-packages\pydantic2ts\cli\script.py", line 165, in generate_json_schema
    master_model.Config.extra = Extra.forbid
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\pdf-creator-HARGFuzC\Lib\site-packages\pydantic\_internal\_model_construction.py", line 215, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(item)
AttributeError: Config
```

If I switch the code to this:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Client(BaseModel):
    clientId: str
    clientName: str
```

The error slightly changes:

```
C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\pdf-creator-HARGFuzC\Lib\site-packages\pydantic\_migration.py:283: UserWarning: `pydantic.generics:GenericModel` has been moved to `pydantic.BaseModel`.
  warnings.warn(f'`{import_path}` has been moved to `{new_location}`.')
2023-12-29 03:42:23,101 Finding pydantic models...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\pdf-creator-HARGFuzC\Scripts\pydantic2ts.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\pdf-creator-HARGFuzC\Lib\site-packages\pydantic2ts\cli\script.py", line 274, in main
    return generate_typescript_defs(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\pdf-creator-HARGFuzC\Lib\site-packages\pydantic2ts\cli\script.py", line 201, in generate_typescript_defs
    models = extract_pydantic_models(import_module(module))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\pdf-creator-HARGFuzC\Lib\site-packages\pydantic2ts\cli\script.py", line 81, in extract_pydantic_models
    for _, model in inspect.getmembers(module, is_concrete_pydantic_model):
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\inspect.py", line 607, in getmembers
    return _getmembers(object, predicate, getattr)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\inspect.py", line 598, in _getmembers
    if not predicate or predicate(value):
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\pdf-creator-HARGFuzC\Lib\site-packages\pydantic2ts\cli\script.py", line 69, in is_concrete_pydantic_model
    return bool(obj.__concrete__)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\pdf-creator-HARGFuzC\Lib\site-packages\pydantic\_internal\_model_construction.py", line 215, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(item)
AttributeError: __concrete__
```

Anyone has any ideas on this error ?
I am replicating a simple scenario according to the documentation.
I have installed globally npm dependency json-schema-to-typescript as per the docs

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was hard to find but eventually found it was a version defect from lib open issues.

Once I updated pedantic dependency to 1.9 it worked.

[https://github.com/phillipdupuis/pydantic-to-typescript/issues/41#:~:text=Using%20Pydantic%201.9%20generated%20correct%20TS%20file.%0AIs%20this%20script%20only%20supposed%20to%20be%20working%20with%20Pydantic%201.x%3F%20I%20didn%27t%20see%20such%20a%20limitation%20in%20documentation.%0AThanks](https://github.com/phillipdupuis/pydantic-to-typescript/issues/41#:%7E:text=Using%20Pydantic%201.9%20generated%20correct%20TS%20file.%0AIs%20this%20script%20only%20supposed%20to%20be%20working%20with%20Pydantic%201.x%3F%20I%20didn%27t%20see%20such%20a%20limitation%20in%20documentation.%0AThanks)!